# Exercise on geometrically connectedness of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I want to prove the following exercise from Götz' & Wedhorn's Algebraic Geometry I on page 144: Chapter 5: Schemes over fields (only part (a); part (b) is a simple consequence):

> **Exercise 5.23.** Let $k$ be a field and let $X$ be a connected $k$-scheme.
>   (a) Assume that there exists a non-empty geometrically connected $k$-scheme $Y$ and a
>   $k$-morphism $f:Y \to X$. Show that $X$ is geometrically connected.
>
> *Hint*: Use Exercise 5.22 to show that $X_{\Omega} \to X$ is open, closed, and surjective for
>   a separable closure $\Omega$ of $k$ and show that there are no nontrivial open and closed
>   subsets of $X_{\Omega}$.

Q: I haven't found the key to show the last part of the exercise that there are no nontrivial open and closed subsets in $X_{\Omega}$.

By proposition 5.53 $X$ is geometrically connected if and only if $X_K= X \times_k Spec \text{ } K$ is connected for certain separable closed field extension 
$k \to K$. thus it suffice to show that $X_{\Omega}$ is connected. because $Y$ is gemetrically connected, the pullback $Y_{\Omega}$ is connected. in addition I partially succeed in proving 5.22 except of the $p:X_{\Omega} \to X$ is open part (???). does it follow from the 'closed' part? I don't see it.

if we continue with the main claim to show that $X_{\Omega}$ is connected then let assume that $X_{\Omega}$ is not connected and we can find a non empty open & closed proper subset $U \subsetneqq X_{\Omega}$. then $p(U)$ is also non empty, open & closed in $X$ and therefore $p(U)= X$ because $X$ connected and $p$ open& closed. Similary  $p(X_{\Omega} \backslash U)= X$.

in addition since $Y_{\Omega}$ is connected one the preimages of $U$ or $X_{\Omega} \backslash U$ under induced map $f_{\Omega}: Y_{\Omega} \to X_{\Omega}$ is empty and the other the whole $Y_{\Omega}$.  at this point I'm a bit lost. can I obtain from this observations a contradiction on non emptyness of $U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint refers to 5.22:

> **Exercise 5.22**. Let $A\to B$ be an integral ring homomorphism. Show that the corresponding morphism of schemes $\operatorname{Spec} B\to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is universally closed. Deduce that if $K$ is an algebraic extension of a field $k$, then the projection $X_K\to X$ is universally open, universally closed, and surjective.

You mention you have not yet proven that $X_K\to X$ is universally open. If we prove this, then we have that $X_\Omega\to X$ is universally open, universally closed and surjective, and then we're in the situation of [your other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3384205/pullback-diagram-connected-irreducible-or-reduced-schemes) that I responded to, where the appropriate fiber product diagram is

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
Y_\Omega @>p_X>> X_\Omega\\
@Vp_YVV @VVfV\\
Y @>g >> X
\end{CD}

where all the schemes besides $X_\Omega$ are connected by assumption. Thus $X_\Omega$ must also be connected by the result at that question.

In order to prove that $X_\omega\to X$ is universally open, it is enough to prove that $\operatorname{Spec} K\to \operatorname{Spec} k$ is universally open for an algebraic field extension $k\subset K$. By a standard locality argument, it's enough to check this on affines. So we want to check that for $R$ any $k$-module, the map $R\to R\otimes_k K$ is open. It suffices to prove that the image of a standard open $D(f)$ is again open for $f\in R\otimes_k K$. In order to do this, pick some finite algebraic $k$-subfield of $F\subset K$ so that $f\in R\otimes_kF$. Then $R\to R\otimes_kF$ is flat and finitely presented, so the image of $D(f)$ from this map is open, and it is the same image as we get when considering $D(f)$ coming from $R\otimes_kK$.

To prove that the images are the same, consider the obvious commutative triangle of schemes $\operatorname{Spec}(R\otimes_k K)_f \stackrel{\alpha}{\to} \operatorname{Spec}(R\otimes_k F)_f \stackrel{\beta}{\to} \operatorname{Spec} R$ where the third side $\beta\circ\alpha$ isn't drawn since diagrams here are difficult. Suppose a prime ideal $p\subset R$ is in the image of $\beta$. This means that $(R\otimes_k F)_f\otimes_R \kappa(p) = (F\otimes_k \kappa(p))_f$ is nonzero, so $F\otimes_k\kappa(p)$ is nonzero and the image of $f$ in it is not nilpotent. Next, the ring map $F\otimes_k \kappa(p)\to K\otimes_k \kappa(p)$ is injective, so $(R\otimes_k K)\otimes_R\kappa(p) = K\otimes_k \kappa(p)$ is not the zero ring and the image of $f$ in it is not nilpotent. So $(R\otimes_k K)\otimes_R \kappa(p)$ isn't the zero ring and we've shown what we wanted.

Comment: the maps $\operatorname{Spec} R\otimes K\to \operatorname{Spec} R$ and $\operatorname{Spec} R\otimes F\to \operatorname{Spec} R$ have same images, because $\operatorname{Spec} R\otimes K\to \operatorname{Spec} R \otimes F$ is closed + dominant (as $\operatorname{Spec} K \to \operatorname{Spec} F$ universally closed + $F \to K$ injective)?

Comment: Sorry, that's unclear. It should be that the image of $D(f)$ coming from $R\otimes_k F$ is the same as the image of $D(f)$ coming from $R\otimes_k K$. Edit made.

Comment: maybe I miss the point: we compose $\operatorname{Spec} R\otimes K \xrightarrow{\alpha} \operatorname{Spec} R\otimes F \xrightarrow{\beta}  \operatorname{Spec} R$ and we want to show that the image $(\beta \circ \alpha) (D(f))$ is open. by choice of $F$ we know that $f \in R\otimes F$, i.e. $f \in im(\alpha^*)$ with canonical embedding $\alpha^*: R\otimes F \to R\otimes K$. you showed that $\beta(D(f))$ is open and my concern is that in order to show $(\beta \circ \alpha) (D(f))$ is open,

Comment: we must have to know that $\alpha(D(f))=D(f)$. if $\alpha$ possibly would not surjective this could fail, thus I asked for surjectivity of $\alpha$. or is this not neccessary? I noticed now that in my previous comment I mixed up $\beta$ with $\alpha$ and thus it becomes quite confusing. I hope that this one makes the detail clearer that I wanted to point out in a very clumsy way.

Comment: I've added a sentence or two about it. Basically the point is to look at the fibers and then that $R\otimes_k F\to R\otimes_k K$ is injective and things are easy.

Comment: probably you wanted to write $(R\otimes_k F)_f\otimes_R \kappa(p) = (F\otimes_k \kappa(p))_f$ is non zero? our goal is to show $(R\otimes_k K)_f\otimes_R \kappa(p)= (K\otimes_k \kappa(p))_f$ not zero ring, as you said. the argument that $R\otimes_k F\to R\otimes_k K$ *implies* that $(R\otimes_k K)\otimes_R\kappa(p) = K\otimes_k \kappa(p)$ is non zero confuses me. $\kappa(p)$ is in general *not* flat over $R$, thus

Comment: tensoring by  $- \otimes_R \kappa(p)$ not preserves injectivity. do I miss a detail? I don't know but possibly you wanted to tensor $F \to K$ by $- \otimes_k \kappa(p)$ and then localize by $f$. this would probably work, since both these extensions are flat. was this maybe your argument?

Comment: I did make one typo on an instance of $F$ versus $K$ and it has been corrected. I have no idea what you're talking about with $\kappa(p)$ and flatness, this is completely besides the point. $R$ is a free $k$-module and $F\to K$ is an injectitve map of free $k$-modules so the result is obvious.

Comment: the point I was talking about was the way you conclude that $(R\otimes_k K)\otimes_R\kappa(p) = K\otimes_k \kappa(p)$ is not empty. was your argument that the non empty ring $(R\otimes_k F)\otimes_R\kappa(p) = F \otimes_k \kappa(p) $ injects into $(R\otimes_k K)\otimes_R\kappa(p) = K\otimes_k \kappa(p)$? and my point was just if you have used this argument that you cannot make the implication "$R\otimes_k F\to R\otimes_k K$ injective $\Rightarrow (R\otimes_k F)\otimes_R\kappa(p) \to (R\otimes_k K)\otimes_R\kappa(p)$ injective",

Comment: because $\kappa(p)$ over $R$ looks not flat. instead I thought that the correct implication might be "$F \to K$ injective $\Rightarrow F \otimes_k \kappa(p) \to K\otimes_k \kappa(p)$ injective", because $\kappa(p)$ is flat over $k$. this concerns just the modus ponens of the conclusion. if I'm missing the point again, could you tell which argument you used concretely to conclude that $R\otimes_k F\to R\otimes_k K$ injective implies $(R\otimes_k K)\otimes_R\kappa(p) = K\otimes_k \kappa(p)$ not zero instead what I tried to explain above.

Comment: Ugh, somehow I wrote $R\otimes_k F\to R\otimes_k K$ when I meant $F\otimes_k \kappa(p)\to K\otimes_k\kappa(p)$ and now it's been corrected. $\kappa(p)$ is still a free nonzero $k$-module, so it's flat over $k$ and tensoring with it over $k$ is exact and preserves injections, like $F\to K$. Sorry for the typos and then not realizing that they were there.